# How do I remove commas and provide proper spacing in java using FileReader/BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io, split

So my output looks like this:

```
namefirst , namelast  , birthday , birthmonth , birthyear , weight , height 

Starlin   , Castro    ,24,3,1990,190,72.8
Madison   , Bumgarner ,1,8,1989,215,76.0
Jason     , Heyward   ,9,8,1989,240,77.3
Ruben     , Tejada    ,27,10,1989,160,71.2
Jenrry    , Mejia     ,11,10,1989,160,72.5
Mike      , Stanton   ,8,11,1989,235,77.9
Dayan     , Viciedo   ,10,3,1989,240,71.1
Chris     , Sale      ,30,3,1989,170,77.2
Freddie   , Freeman   ,12,9,1989,225,77.7
Clayton   , Kershaw   ,19,3,1988,225,75.4
Travis    , Snider    ,2,2,1988,235,72.0
Elvis     , Andrus    ,26,8,1988,200,72.0
Trevor    , Cahill    ,1,3,1988,220,76.0
Rick      , Porcello  ,27,12,1988,200,77.0
Brett     , Anderson  ,1,2,1988,235,76.5
Fernando  , Martinez  ,10,10,1988,200,73.0
Jhoulys   , Chacin    ,7,1,1988,215,75.2
Chris     , Tillman   ,15,4,1988,200,77.8
Neftali   , Feliz     ,2,5,1988,215,75.5
Craig     , Kimbrel   ,28,5,1988,205,71.6
```

However, I want to remove the commas and align the data under the proper headings. Any help with this? This is my splitting code so far:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {  
  File csvFile = new File("BaseballNames1.csv");
  ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
  int recordCount = 0;
  BufferedReader br = null;
  FileReader fr = null;


  try
  {   
        fr  = new FileReader(csvFile);
        br  = new BufferedReader(fr);  


        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            records.add(line);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++)
        {                 

             String[] array = records.get(recordCount).split(",");
             String firstName = array[0].trim();
             String lastName = array[1].trim();
             String birthDay = array[2].trim();
             String birthMonth = array[3].trim();
             String birthYear = array[4].trim();
             String weight = array[5].trim();
             String height = array[6].trim();

             System.out.println(records.get(i));   
        }

        br.close();
        fr.close();

  }
  catch(IOException ioe)
  {
     ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Please keep in mind I am a beginner at Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a two step approach here. First do the first pass looking for the maximum length between all elements of the same column. For example, look for the max length for the first name. Then, on the second pass print the values of the columns formatted.

Something like

```
         String[] array = records.get(recordCount).split(",");
         String firstName = array[0].trim();
         if (maxFirstName > firstName.length())
            maxFirstName = firstName.length();
```

On the second pass:
             String[] array = records.get(recordCount).split(",");
             String firstName = array[0].trim();

and pass the firstName to pad to either left or right:

```
public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
     return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  
}

public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%1$" + n + "s", s);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will seprate your code using comma and will return array of string

```
 String [] commaEliminatedLine = line.split(",");
```